# Can I use AppController and ModuleController at a same time?

Tags: cakephp

I have a table called settings. I created a controller for this as settings controller.

```
<?php 
      class SettingsController extends AppController {
         ....
         ....
      }
?>
```

By default I have app controller

```
<?php
     class AppController extends Controller {
        ....
        ....
     }
?>
```

In app controller I put some logic in beforeFilter method which is common for all controllers, Now I have to user some logics in beforeFilter in settings controller. But, I am unable to do so.. If I put beforeFilter in settings controller it doesn't access logics from appController before filetr,

Can anyone advice regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone advice regarding this?

Yes, learn about the basics of [OOP in php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) first before trying to use an OOP based framework. Especially pay attention to the [overloading section](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) for what you want to do.

SettingsController already inherits the code from AppController because it extends it. The examples in the manual of the framework should already show you this:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    // Your code here
    parent::beforeFilter();
    // Your code here
}
```

You need to call the parent method.